# Python Tkinter Exception

Tags: python, tkinter

I get a tkinter exception during my script:
Here is the code:

```
def readconf(startmenu):
    gui_mainmenu (wlc_current, wlcsession, startmenu)

def gui_startmenu():
startmenu=Tk()
startmenu.title ( "Netcloud WLC-Config" )
logo = PhotoImage ( file="nc-logo.ppm" )
w1 = Label ( startmenu, image=logo ).pack ()
explanation = """Welcome to the Netcloud WLC-Sripting Tool"""
w2 = Label ( startmenu,
             justify=LEFT,
             pady=20,
             text=explanation ).pack ()
btn_menu1 = Button ( startmenu, text='Login to WLC', command=lambda: readconf(startmenu)).pack ( fill=X )
btn_menu6 = Button ( startmenu, text='Exit', command=lambda: sys.exit ( 0 ) ).pack ( fill=X, padx=100, pady=50 )
startmenu.mainloop ()

def gui_mainmenu(wlc, wlcsession, startmenu):
    startmenu.destroy ()  # Destroy the Startmenu
    set_APInfos ( wlc, wlcsession )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Start Menu
    gui_startmenu()
```

When I call the function set_APInfos() I get this exception:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/burgener/Documents/Scripting/scripts/WLC-Config/WLC-configurator.py", line 191, in set_APInfos
    wlcsession.sendcommand ( "config ap name '" + ap_new_name[i] + "' " + apnames[i] )
  File "/Users/burgener/Documents/Scripting/scripts/WLC-Config/libCuwn.py", line 101, in sendcommand
    self.cli.send(command+"\n")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 716, in send
    return self._send(s, m)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1082, in _send
    raise socket.error('Socket is closed')
OSError: Socket is closed
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/burgener/Documents/Scripting/scripts/WLC-Config/WLC-configurator.py", line 593, in <lambda>
    btn_menu1 = Button ( startmenu, text='Login to WLC', command=lambda: readconf(startmenu)).pack ( fill=X )
  File "/Users/burgener/Documents/Scripting/scripts/WLC-Config/WLC-configurator.py", line 116, in readconf
    gui_mainmenu (wlc_current, wlcsession, startmenu)
  File "/Users/burgener/Documents/Scripting/scripts/WLC-Config/WLC-configurator.py", line 600, in gui_mainmenu
    set_APInfos ( wlc, wlcsession )
  File "/Users/burgener/Documents/Scripting/scripts/WLC-Config/WLC-configurator.py", line 195, in set_APInfos
    print ( "Error: Connection failed to WLC: %s\n" % wlcsession.hostname )
AttributeError: 'WlcSession' object has no attribute 'hostname'
```

Comment: You're not receiving a tkinter exception, tkinter is firing a callback which has an error in it. You haven't actually shown us the code that is causing either exception.

Comment: This doesn't directly relate to your question, but I see an important bug in that code. The Tkinter layout `.pack` method returns `None`, so all of those names like `w1`, `btn_menu1`, etc will equal `None`, not your GUI's widgets.